# Qthread exec(), event loop and connection with context

Tags: qt, qthread

I am trying to connect a QThread::finished on another thread with an event loop in order to request a quit()

Consider this code :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>

class DummyThread : public QThread
{
public:
    DummyThread::DummyThread(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QThread(parent){}
protected:
    virtual void run() override{
        QThread::sleep(1);
        qDebug()<<"Work done!";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QThread masterThread;
    DummyThread childThread;

    // This connection is Queued but doesn't work, you can force direct connection but this is not what I want...
    QObject::connect(&childThread, &QThread::finished, &masterThread, &QThread::quit /*, Qt::ConnectionType::DirectConnection*/);

    childThread.start();
    masterThread.start(); //do a exec()
    masterThread.wait();

    return 0; //No need for an event loop here
}
```

This is a dummy exemple just to understand the problem here, the connection should be queued and the quit() executed in the masterThread event loop.
But nothing happens here :-(

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried starting the masterThread first before starting the childThread?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31972037/qthread-will-not-exit) help?

Comment: @NickM.Yes, same thing

Comment: @JarMan Yes, it is something like this